# c++ what fstream write function write to file (coden in post)

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm don't understand what is written to a file `file.write((char *) this, sizeof(BOOK)) ;`. Please explain :)

```
void add_new_book(int tcode,char tname[33], char tauthor[26], float tprice, int tcopies, int tavail)
{
    fstream file ;
    file.open("BOOK.DAT", ios::app) ;
    bookcode = tcode ;
    strcpy(name,tname) ;
    strcpy(author,tauthor) ;
    price = tprice ;
    copies = tcopies ;
    avail = tavail ;
    file.write((char *) this, sizeof(BOOK)) ; }
```

Comment: Your code is not complete enough to be understandable. Please provide a self-contained example, after checking that it compiles and run somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably the function you have quoted is a member function of a `class BOOK`, and the `write` call will simply dump the entire binary representation of the current `BOOK` instance into the file. (`this` is of type `BOOK*`.)

This is usually not a very portable or sensible thing to do, since future consumers of the serialized data have no way of knowing the actual serialization format. (The future consumer may be yourself on a different machine or a different compiler.) Look up proper serialization strategies if you want to take this seriously.

Comment: This function write data of all char variables to file ?  `file.write((char *) this, sizeof(BOOK)) ;`. Please explain :)

Comment: The explanation is exactly what I posted: The *binary representation of the class* is written out. It's not a good idea to do this, since you have very little control over what actually comes out.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Sorry. It was not about any misspelling. More about English language usage. `careful` does not fit here while `sensible` does. Maybe you meant: `and you must be careful in its usage`?

Answer (score 0):

```
    void add_new_book (BOOK &book){    // call the function as: add_new_book(book1);
        fstream file ;                 // where book1 is an object of class BOOK
        file.open("BOOK.DAT", ios::app) ;
        bookcode = book.bookcode ;
        strcpy(name,book.name) ;
        strcpy(author,book.author) ;
        price = book.price ;
        copies = book.copies ;
        avail = book.avail ;
        file.write((char *)this, sizeof(BOOK)) ;
        file.close() ;    //don't forget to close the file 
    }
```